# Getting error when trying to Create Subscription from smart button

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to subscribe paypal billing plan from Smart Payment Buttons.
But continuously  I am getting error "The specified resource does not exist."

```
paypal.Buttons({

    createSubscription: function (data, actions) {

        return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'P-1G3183167U24246113LMNZLY'
        });
    },

    onApprove: function (data, actions) {

        alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
    }


}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

[image: This is code for subscribe using smart button]

Subscription Api response error:

> {
>       "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
>       "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
>       "debug_id": "82ac38ce75745",
>       "details": [
>           {
>               "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
>               "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
>           }
>       ],
>       "links": [
>           {
>               "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
>               "rel": "information_link",
>               "method": "GET"
>           }
>       ] }

Error image:

[image: error image]

Answer (score 7):

I was having the identical issue, and found the solution (for me at least).

While having this issue, I was using the Plan-ID from an actual real Plan (in Draft status) that I had created in the PayPal web dashboard UI. I thought that was allowed while testing with the PayPal Sandbox. It's not.

You *must* follow [PayPal's instructions here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#) to create a Fake Test Product and Fake Test Plan using the PayPal REST API (via bash+curl or other API testing tool like Postman). You can't create your test Product+Plan via any web UI, and you can't test against a real-world Product+Plan, even if that Product is still in Draft status.

After creating your Fake Test Product+Plan via PayPal's REST API, then you can plug the Plan-ID returned by the REST API into your JavaScript for the PayPal buttons on your site.

Also: make sure that in your script tag, you are using the Client-ID from a PayPal Sandbox Business account, not your actual real-world PayPal account.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, however it seems that at this moment paypal sandobx is refusing connections, at least from postman. Wierd ehough that you can't just use the paypal UI to create a plan for testing....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're developing this against a **live account**, as per line 201 `env: 'live'` which it is not a good practice, for instance, breaking functionality in a live site.

I had a the same issue using Java and apparently you can only use one billing plan per subscription, which means you need to create a billing plan for each subscription.

You can find more information in [Paypal REST APIs documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-plan/#).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this. `'plan_id': 'P-1G3183167U24246113LMNZLY'`. First you need to check whether your account has a plan with such a plan_id. If not you need to create a product first then create a plan and then you can use your plan_id in smart buy button.

Just follow the instructions in this page:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/?mark=seat-based%20pricing#